# specify OUTFILE path

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using **MySQL** database on a **Ubuntu** machine, and running the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT id,name FROM cars 
INTO OUTFILE 'my_cars.dat'

LOAD DATA INFILE 'my_cars.dat' INTO TABLE all_cars(id, name);
```

It works. **But** how can I also specify the **path** to where the `my_cars.dat` file is put??

I mean , for example, I want the `my_cars.dat` file to be put under `/data/temp` , how can I specify this??

I tried to use `... INTO OUTFILE '/data/temp/my_cars.dat' ...` but it does not work...

I got error :

```
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/data/temp/my_cars.dat' (Errcode: 13)
```

Comment: > but it does not work...
Why? Do you get an error? If yes then what's in error message?

Answer (score 0):

What user are you running mysql as? Does it have write permissions to /data/temp?

Answer (score 0):

A couple potential reasons:

1. (and I suspect it's this) The `outfile` is written by the client, so it can only write to where you have write privileges.  Assuming `/data/temp` exists (see #2), it is most likely owned by `mysql:mysql` or `root:root`, and privs `700`.
2. MySQL's default location (in Ubuntu, at least) is `/var/lib/mysql`, so make sure that `/data/temp` exists.

Comment: And what are the permissions on it?

Comment: I have also write permission.